# Geiger Counter vs PIN Detector

Tags: particle-physics, x-rays, x-ray-crystallography

I have noticed in many papers that test Moseley's law use PIN detectors instead of Geiger counters to measure the XRF spectrums of elements. Why is that? is it because Geiger counters signal also depend on the intensity of the x-rays which makes hard to resolve energy?

Comment: Basic Geiger counters don’t measure energy at all. If an ionizing event occurs in the chamber you get a count.

Comment: A "Gieger counter" is a Gieger-Müller tube being run in saturation mode, so that it is *by design* not sensitive to energy. You can run the tube in the proportional regime if you want, but that cost you lower sensitivity, requires calibration, and requires more sophisticated electronics (which I suspect was the driving from for using them primarily in saturation in the early days).